# Logback Config File is Removed from Weblogic 10.3.5

Tags: weblogic, logback

I have an ADF application deployed on weblogic 10.3.5

I added logback to this application, and added `logback.xml` into `WEB-INF/classes`

Cnce I deploy the application, it starts logging normally into files (appenders) I defined in `logback.xml`.

After few hours, logback starts showing logs into console! Although I don't have an "STDOUT" appender, and it stops adding logs into files I defined in logback.xml

It seems that logback.xml is removed someway, and logback is using its basic configurations.

Comment: What does the output on the console say?

Comment: I am away from the application now, but the logs appear on console was something like

DEBUG,10 JUN 2012 13:39:31,306 DEBUG [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' - DebugLogMessage

Answer (score 0):

When logback encounters a problem can print internal messages on the console [if instructed to do so](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#automaticStatusPrinting). These internal messages can be a very useful source of information for tracking logback's behavior. Also note that in response to I/O failures, logback may suspend relevant appenders momentarily and seamlessly recover when I/O returns to normal.